# Helm templating: Get the value of loop value inside a templating file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

I'm trying to do somewhat advanced templating. But not able to progress so far.

The idea is to get the config/file.conf to template the values properly while doing a loop in configmap file. I've added the respective code snippet for your reference.

Any help is appreciated.

#### Values.yaml

```yaml
global:
  teacher: bob

class:
  primary:
    name: rajesh
    teacher: {{.Values.global.teacher}}

  secondary:
    name: job
    teacher: {{.Values.global.teacher}}
```

#### config/file.conf

```
name={{ .name }}
teacher={{ .teacher }}
```

#### templates/configmap.yaml

```
{{- $currentScope := .}}
{{- range $jobName, $jobData := .Values.class }}
{{- if $jobData.enabled }}
{{- with $currentScope }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ $jobName }}
data:
{{- range $path, $_ := .Files.Glob "config/*" }}
    {{ base $path | nindent 2 }}: |-
      {{- with $currentScope }}
      {{- $var := .Files.Get $path }}
      {{- include "common.tplvalues.render" (dict "value" $var "context" $) | nindent 6 }}
      {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

#### Chart.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: ch
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
dependencies:
  - name: common
    version: 2.x.x
    repository: oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts
```

Comment: What problem are you running into?  I'm guessing `common.tplvalues.render` is from the [`bitnami/common` chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/common/templates/_tplvalues.tpl); can you use the Helm-specific [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) function directly, or use some other way to insert that shared value?